# Node sequelize The auto generated column (created_at, updated_at is not underscored)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize, I used the command line with "--underscored" specified to create model.

This is User model:

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        company_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {
        underscored: true,
    });
    User.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        User.belongsTo(models.Company);
        User.belongsToMany(models.WorkingDay, { through: 'UsersWorkingDays', as: 'days' })
    };
    return User;
};
```

This is company model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Company = sequelize.define('Company', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        underscored: true,
    });
    Company.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Company.hasMany(models.User, { as: 'employees'})
    };

    return Company;
};
```

These are the database:
[image]
[image]

This is the api

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {

    let company = await Company.findByPk(req.params.id, { include: ['employes'] });

    res.json(company);
});
```

This is the result:

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "name": "Huel - Kihn",
    "createdAt": "2019-12-01T03:55:41.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-01T03:55:41.000Z",
    "employees": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "Randi54@hotmail.com",
            "first_name": "Koby",
            "last_name": "Jaskolski",
            "company_id": 13,
            "createdAt": "2019-12-01T03:55:41.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-12-01T03:55:41.000Z",
            "CompanyId": 13
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "email": "Patience.Schuppe63@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "Althea",
            "last_name": "O'Hara",
            "company_id": 13,
            "createdAt": "2019-12-01T03:55:41.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2019-12-01T03:55:41.000Z",
            "CompanyId": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the createdAt and updatedAt from the result is not underscored. But the column for those two are underscored. Are there any way to make the sequelize to use the database column name?

And there is an extra "CompanyId" column in the "employees" field, how can I prevent that of showing?

I have tried to search online but I did not find any solution.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that stumbles on this, there is an option for each timestamp Sequelize auto-generates.

Here is the reference in the [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-init) or if you want to check out the [code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/1c1aa33068c608ad5c66a18d8aae27c697a5d89e/lib/model.js#L1034-L1049) directly.

```
sequelize.define('Model', { ... }, {
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  deletedAt: 'deleted_at' // if you have paranoid on as well
});

// OR

Model.init({ ... }, {
  createdAt: 'created_at',
  updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  deletedAt: 'deleted_at' 
});
```